# Arch Linux Using the Wrong MTA

Tags: arch-linux, email

I try to do this:

```
$ mail -s "Hello world" foo@example.com
This is a test from my server
EOT
```

…and get this:

```
/usr/sbin/ssmtp: No such file or directory
$ "/home/user//dead.letter" 9/248
. . . message not sent.
```

Which makes sense, because I uninstalled SSMTP in favor of Postfix. How do I change it so `mail` uses the right MTA?

Comment: Have you done all the necessary postfix configurations ? If not, take a look at these links: http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-postfix-masquerade-change-email-mail-address.html and : https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Postfix_Local_Mail

Comment: Guiney: Also, if you are using postfix MTA with sendMail, then you need to set it like :

set sendmail="/usr/bin/yourPostfixMailDir" .

I will suggest , you again try to see if you have completed all the configurations properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh man, that’ll teach me to [RTFM](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Postfix_Local_Mail)—I had everything set up correctly; all I had to do was start the postfix daemon. (After that, a backlog of undelivered e-mail from a month ago arrived in my inbox!) I guess I forgot to add it to my rc.conf after I installed it, so it didn’t start back up again after one of my infrequent reboots.